# connecting to webpage in localhost in my mysql database - php

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, localhost, html

the problem i have is that i would like to put a specfic webpage link for a user in their database table, however the webpage is on my localhost.

i have not fiqured a way of showing a link on the webpage that connects to the specfic localhost webpage.

i have been able to show links of other websites such as google and connect to them but i have not been able to do it with a page on my localhost.

the question wasn't going through so i included some dummy code.

```
        $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facultytable order by id");
        echo "<select facultyname=myselect>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[facultyname]</a></option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        ?>
```

Comment: You're missing an opening `<a>` tag for starters...

Comment: Define "a page on my localhost."  If you want people to access a page hosted on a web server on your computer, they'll need to be able to access that web server from wherever they are.

Comment: A WAN IP address or a remote webserver cannot connect to your internal IP and NAT routed ect based on a http link to localhost. you need to use your WAN IP for clients outside your network and route them to your internal IP(server) or your LAN IP if the clients are on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution to my problem online

[adding hyperlink to mysql results](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/189068/add-hyperlink-to-mysql-results-in-php)